# Efficiently adding to the shortest bucket

Tags: python

I'm trying to divide up people into different groups, and I want to be able to always add new people to the emptiest group.

I have a dictionary which contains people, and the group they are in, and a list of new people to add 'evenly' to the groups:

```
groups = {
    'alice': 'a',
    'bob': 'b',
    'charles': 'c',
    'dawn': 'd',
    'eric': 'a',
    'frank': 'b',
    'gina': 'd',
    'henry': 'd'
}

people = ['ian', 'jess', 'keith', 'lila', 'mike', 'nell', 'owen', 'patty']
```

I'm doing this currently by working out which is the emptiest group, adding the next person assigned to that group, then re-counting:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

for person in people:
    counts = Counter(groups.values())
    print(counts)
    emptiest = min(counts.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
    groups[person] = emptiest[0]
    print(groups)
```

However it's a bit inefficient to recalculate the emptiest group each time. Can anyone suggest a better way to achieve this?

Comment: can your data structure be changed? I.E a dict of group names as the key and a list of users in the group as a list for the value?

Comment: Yes - I don't mind doing that operation once in my code if it makes the overall code more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT - address existing people in groups**:

If you have existing people in groups, you can do the following:

```py
groups = {
    'alice': 'a',
    'bob': 'b',
    'charles': 'c',
    'dawn': 'd',
    'eric': 'a',
    'frank': 'b',
    'gina': 'd',
    'henry': 'd'
}

# create dictionary like {group: [list of people]}
groups_d = {g: [] for g in groups.values()}
for p, g in groups.items():
    groups_d[g].append(p)

people = ['ian', 'jess', 'keith', 'lila', 'mike', 'nell', 'owen', 'patty']

for p in people:
    # get dictionary like {number of people: group}
    # note: groups with the same length will be overwritten,
    # but it doesn't matter
    len_dict = {len(pp): g for g, pp in groups_d.items()}

    # append to group with minimum length
    groups_d[len_dict[min(len_dict.keys())]].append(p)
```

Again, there are more "vectorized" approaches, e.g. you could fill up groups until they are all equal, then switch to the proposed solution below which is clearly faster.

**Previous answer**:
I think the big inefficiency lies in the fact that you use a format like `{person: group}` instead of `{group_name: [person1, person2, ...]}`.
This also has the disadvantage that two people with the same name will break the logic.

Also, once all the groups have the same number of people, then you can simply cycle through them in order, there's no need to re-count.

```py
import itertools

groups = ['a', 'b', 'c']
people = ['alice', 'barbara', 'chris', 'diego', 'emanuel', 'florence']
groups_d = {g: [] for g in groups}

groups_cycling = itertools.cycle(groups)

for p in people:
    groups_d[next(groups_cycling)].append(p)
```

which gives

```py
>>> groups_d

{'a': ['alice', 'diego'],
 'b': ['barbara', 'emanuel'],
 'c': ['chris', 'florence']}
```

you can then convert to your desired output through a simple dictionary comprehension:

```py
>>> {p:g for g, people in groups_d.items() for p in people}

{'alice': 'a',
 'diego': 'a',
 'barbara': 'b',
 'emanuel': 'b',
 'chris': 'c',
 'florence': 'c'}
```

To state the obvious, the best is to simply turn your list of people in to a matrix (e.g. number of column being the number of groups, and number of rows being the amount of people in each group). Assuming you'll end up having an uneven number of people, you'll have to take care of some missing values, but it should be trivial.
This is akin to asking people to put themselves in `n` lines.

Comment: Yes, I can see that reversing the data structure makes cycling and topping up easier, but I don't think this deals with adding to the existing set of groups, with uneven counts?

Answer (score 1):

by changing the data structure to `group_name: [list of names]` you can take advantage of the fact that getting the length of a list is fast and doesnt need to iterate over the elements to count them. So its run/complexity/efficency is O(1) . So you could just use min to get the shortest length list using key and then appending to that list.

```py
groups = {
    'a': ['alice', 'eric'],
    'b': ['bob', 'frank'],
    'c': ['charles'],
    'd': ['dawn','gina','henry']
}

people = ['ian', 'jess', 'keith', 'lila', 'mike', 'nell', 'owen', 'patty']
for person in people:
    min(groups.values(), key=lambda names: len(names)).append(person)

print(groups)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'a': ['alice', 'eric', 'jess', 'mike'], 'b': ['bob', 'frank', 'keith', 'nell'], 'c': ['charles', 'ian', 'lila', 'owen'], 'd': ['dawn', 'gina', 'henry', 'patty']}
```

Comment: Nice - given that it still has to re-evaluate `groups.values()` after each change I'm not sure there's not a more (time) efficient solution only calculating lengths once and storing changes. But this is nicer than my initial approach. Only comment is that the `lambda` is unnecessary since `len` alone is a valid function for `key=`